# Animating a texture growing & fading with a Unity 2D particle system

Tags: unity, 2d, particles

I've created texture which could represent a lightning orb.
Is it possible to animate scaling of the texture to simulate this lighting burst? Like the orb is growing and than fades away.

Or do I need to make sequence of similar images and then animate it as particle system in Unity?

Comment: You're aware of the "size over lifetime" particle system component?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to randomize the rotation along with this value ?

Comment: You're aware of the "start rotation" → "random between two constants" setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan said, your looking for the size over lifetime, and the color over lifetime can control opacity. Just keep tweeking the particle system, even if its just one particle